# develop login application with coldfusion and java

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am a beginner in ColdFusion. I just went through some tutorial to know the basic tags and functions used in ColdFusion. I am interested in developing a simple web application with Login functionality as the first step, where the username and password, entered in the form are validated in the back-end java code. I am not able to find out how to call a back-end java function to make the validation when the form is submitted. It would be of great help to start off my journey with ColdFusion.

Comment: `<cfset javaObject = createObject("java","location.of.code")>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is there a reason you want to create the login validation in java?  You may not be understanding what ColdFusion can do for you. You can create a fully-functional login using HTML, ColdFusion, and its connection to a relational database. [This tutorial touches on a lot of that functionality](http://cftutorial.blogspot.com/).

It is possible to [compile java objects and call them using ColdFusion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7880.html), but this is definitely not beginner intro to ColdFusion tutorial material.

Comment: +1. As CF runs on java, it is certainly easy enough to interact with java objects. However, I am also wondering *why* you want to incorporate java. ie Do you really need it or is it just unnecessary complexity. Can you give us some background? Are you building a CF layer to interact with an *existing* java application, ...?

Comment: Thanks @Digital Chris. that gave me a better understanding

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to call methods on Java objects in CFML. One just creates the Java object instance and then... calls methods on it.  EG:

```
<cfscript>
    string = createObject("java", "java.lang.String").init("my string"); // init() calls the appropriate constructor
    indexOf = string.indexOf("ring");
    charAt = string.charAt(4);
    toCharArray = string.toCharArray();
    toUpperCase = string.toUpperCase();
    writeDump([string,indexOf,charAt,toCharArray,toUpperCase]);
</cfscript>
```

There's often some monkeying around to do with type-casting: CFML's loose/dynamic typing needs marshalling before sending to Java sometimes. Look up [`javaCast()`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/JavaCast) for that.

But that's basically it.